# Images are reloading when scrolling listView in Android

Tags: android, image, listview, reload

I have a listView where I put a Title and a description with a picture and the pictures reloads when I scroll up, how could I resolve this problem? I tried some solutions but they failed...

Here is my code:

**GETVIEW**

```
public class ViewHolder extends ArrayAdapter<ListViewModel> {

    public ViewHolder(Context context, List<ListViewModel> model) {
        super(context, 0, model);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View cView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(cView == null){
            cView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_list_holder,parent, false);
        }
        ListViewHolder viewHold = (ListViewHolder) cView.getTag();
        if(viewHold == null){
            viewHold = new ListViewHolder();
            viewHold.title = (TextView) cView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            viewHold.content = (TextView) cView.findViewById(R.id.content);
            viewHold.picture = (ImageView) cView.findViewById(R.id.picture);
            cView.setTag(viewHold);
        }

        ListViewModel model = getItem(position);
        viewHold.title.setText(model.getTitle());
        viewHold.content.setText(model.getContent());
        if (viewHold.picture != null)
            new DownloadImageTask(viewHold.picture).execute(model.getPicture());
        return cView;
    }

    private class ListViewHolder{
        public TextView title;
        public TextView content;
        public ImageView picture;
    }
}
```

**ImageDownloader**

```
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap myImage = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return myImage;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: that's what recycling does. it calls `getView` over and over again. For images, there are tons of libraries that can help you handle the loading and caching, and releasing of the asynctask.

Comment: as @njzk2 said that's what recycling does. either you can keep images in cache and before downloading again check if they are already downloaded or just some library that handles cache and loading for you like Picasso http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: I was trying to id without other libraries ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Volley instead of AsyncTask:

http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html

It has built in support for image caching as well as cancelling requests if a particular set of images are no longer needed if the user has scrolled away.

Comment: I added Volley but I'm getting troubles when i try to link my getview to volley

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just save the images in a bitmap array in the activity? Then just display those. Therefore they never reload, they are just in activity to be used in the view?

Comment: Where can i create the Array ? I mean, in which activity should i save ?

Comment: Save it in the activity that is using the images and the image loader. Or you could create a class call ImageHolder that just holds all the images in an array, then you can just pass that class to and from the activities. If you did this then you would have to create the object as serializable. Look at [serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) and [intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)